# Spring MVC with XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-3

I'm learning SpringMVC via Mkyong.com tutorials. In his tutorials, Maven is used to build the programs.

I'm not using Maven to build it in this programs.

My Sample Code:

Coffee.java

```
package com.springMVC;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "coffee")
public class Coffee {

    String name;
    int quanlity;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQuanlity() {
        return quanlity;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setQuanlity(int quanlity) {
        this.quanlity = quanlity;
    }

    public Coffee(String name, int quanlity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quanlity = quanlity;
    }

    public Coffee() {
    }

}
```

**XMLController.java**

```
package com.springMVC;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.springMVC.Coffee;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/coffee")
public class XMLController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Coffee getCoffeeInXML(@PathVariable String name) {

        Coffee coffee = new Coffee(name, 100);

        return coffee;

    }
```

**mvc-dispacter-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springMVC" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**[image: my code structure:]**

Please give me a URI(example:https:\localhost:8080/MVCXML/rest/coffee/arabic) to view an output like in MkYong.com tutorial(http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/)

Comment: The only thing you can learn at mkyong.com is how to trick search engines to push your site to the top of the search results. Go to the VMWare site and follow Spring MVC tutorials from the Spring people.

Comment: your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml has the wrong package name in `context:component-scan`.

Comment: @Kevin - now i changed the package name but i'm getting the same problem.

Comment: What does the log show when you start the application under jetty/tomcat? what happens if you hit `http://localhost:8080/rest/coffee/arabic`? Do you see an exception in the log at either of these two points? It's not clear to me what your exact problem is.

Comment: @Kevin The error is "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MVCXML/coffee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the URL mapping works:

1. web.xml routes urls with a prefix to some servlet, and you have mapped everything with prefix /rest/ to the spring DispatcherServlet.
2. The controller routing is handled by the parameter to the `@Controller` annotation, which you've annotated with `/coffee`
3. Then there's a variable at the end that is the name of the coffee, which gets placed in the `@PathVariable`.

So nowhere in there do I see `/MVCXML/`. mkyong.com didn't provide a web.xml so it's a little unclear what the prefix is supposed to be, if you don't already know how web.xml and Spring's dispatcher servlet work together.

The correct URI should be `http://localhost:8080/rest/coffee/arabic`.